# Get attribute of embed element Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, embed

How can I get the value of `flashvars` attribute?

```
<div>
<embed  height="360" 
    src="//www.youtube.com/get_player?enablejsapi=1" 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    width="100%" 
    allowfullscreen="true" 
    allowscriptaccess="always" 
    bgcolor="#fff" 
    scale="noScale" 
    wmode="opaque" 
    flashvars="fmt_list=34%2F640x336%2F9%2F0%2F115%2C5%2F426x224%2F7%2F0%2F0&amp;fmt_stream_map=34%7Chttp%3A%2F%2Fredirector.googlevideo.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fid%3Da067d9378dddd818%26itag%3D34%26source%3Dpicasa%26cmo%....">
</embed>
</div>
```

I am using `getElementsByTagName` to get the element

```
var codedLink = content.document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
```

but when I try `codedLink.flashvars` I get undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName), returns an array of dom element references, so you need to access the element by using array index first

you need to use

```
codedLink[0].getAttribute('flashvars')
```

Comment: I already tried it but unfortunately i got the same output 'undefinded', I read somewhere that i should use `XPCNativeWrapper.unwrap(codedLink)` but i get `HTMLEmbedElement`

Comment: @user2463937 can you try `codedLink[0].getAttribute('flashvars')`

Comment: it did work :D thanks a looooot ^^
and really thanks a lot for your quick answers

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.attr("/* attribute name */")`

```
$(document).ready( function() {
      console.log($('embed').attr('flashvars'));

});
```